# HttpResponseMessage fails to deserialize XML but filestream is fine

Tags: c#, xsd, deserialization

I'm trying to consume a third party webservice. I craft a request message, send it to the httpclient and receive the httpResponseMessage.

Below is a snippet from the method that handles the call. xml = true for my situation.

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClientInstance.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            if (xml)
            {
                try
                {

                    //This fails with "the data at the root level is invalid"
                    XmlMediaTypeFormatter xmlFormatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = true };
                    var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(new Collection<MediaTypeFormatter> { xmlFormatter });

                    return content.Result;
                }
                catch (Exception tempe)
                {
                    var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                    return content.Result;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                return content.Result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _logWriter.LogProcessFault(operationContext, null, GetCurrentMethod(), $"An error occurred while calling the API. URI = {endpoint}. StatusCode = {response.StatusCode}", null);
            throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
```

After running this code, an error is thrown when attempting to deserialize the XML data in the stream. It fails with an error "the data at the root level is invalid".

I commented out the XMLMediaTypeFormatter and response.Content.Read... and replaced it with this

```
                    var fileStream = File.Create("D:\\Extract\\test.txt");
                    await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Close();
```

which writes out valid XML to a file.

In the immediate window I ran response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() and the returned string value has extra backslashes escaping content.

For instance, this is what is in the generated test.txt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and this is from ReadAsStringAsync:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
```

I believe this is what is causing the deserialization to fail. Is there a clean fix for this or perhaps I am doing something wrong elsewhere?

Comment: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>` I'm guessing this is what you see when you look at string content in the debugger? If yes, then it looks correct.  Debugger shows string in the escaped format since debugger allows you to change values of variables.  So if you were to change your string, you'd input it in the same form it would appear in your code.  So that wouldn't be cause of your issue.  Also, BOM, if present, shouldn't be causing xml parser to fail.

Comment: Yes, that is what I see in the string content after ReadAsStringAsync(). I wasn't sure about the BOM though another SO question stated the BOM broke their deserializer and they tossed the first byte of the stream before deserializing it.

Comment: I wonder if reading file somehow tosses BOM away and that's why it works.  Try reading it into a string buffer first, then seeing in debugger if resulting string contains BOM (or possibly into memory buffer, and examining the first couple of bytes to see if those are BOM)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the following block of code

```
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();

                //This fails with "the data at the root level is invalid"
                XmlMediaTypeFormatter xmlFormatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = true };
                var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(new Collection<MediaTypeFormatter> { xmlFormatter });
```

HTTP responses can be consumed only once.  In other words, response is not read into some buffer from which multiple reads can be serviced.  It reads it directly off of the socket.  So once read, it cannot be read again.

Above, you copy response into a file.  That consumes the response and it is no longer available to be read again.  So by the time you try to read it again when assigning to `content`, it reads nothing, so the XML parser (in formatter) throws xml syntax error b/c it basically receives an empty string.

Not sure why you're saving to file, but once saved to file, you can simply read the file and send its contents to xml parser, and your code should now work.  And of course if you remove saving to file, you should be able to read and parse contents of the response just fine.

Comment: I'll update the post. I added the file write for debug purposes. Mainly to see if there was a BOM which might not be shown in the immediate window. The second call was originally the only call and was failing.

Comment: @DavidJacobsen I see, what happens if you uncomment it back in, but instead read contents of the file and try to deserialize.  Does it work then?

Comment: Yes it does. It's part of why I think there is a 'cleaner' answer and not a bug to be reported with the third party.

Comment: at this point I'm completely lost. I commented out the code that wrote it to file, then read the file into filestream and then serialized the filestream (which worked) and just ran my original code... and no error. Since even my versioning is showing i'm back on my original code I can only guess that something changed in the data being sent from the third party API.